# Cannot print to Brother network printer

Tags: drivers, printing, brother

I have 2 computers with Ubuntu 16.04 and KDE desktop.
Both computers are connected to a printer model {{Brother MFC-J5910DW}}, via wifi.

I have the same versions of drivers in both computers:

```
$ dpkg -l|grep -i brother
 brscan-skey 0.2.4-1  amd64        
  Brother Linux scanner S-KEY tool
brscan4 0.4.4-1 amd64 
  Brother Scanner Driver
mfcj6910dwcupswrapper:i386 3.0.0-1 i386
  Brother CUPS Inkjet Printer Definitions
mfcj6910dwlpr:i386 3.0.0-1 i386
  Brother lpr Inkjet Printer Definitions
printer-driver-brlaser 3-5~ubuntu1 amd64
  printer driver for (some) Brother laser printers
printer-driver-ptouch 1.4-1 amd64
   printer driver Brother P-touch label printers
```

I can do ping to the printer in both computers:

```
ping 192.168.1.131
```

or access the printer with a browser (http://192.168.1.131), so there are no connectivity issues.

With one computer I can print perfectly and with the other one I cannot print any page.

If I do this:

```
cupsctl LogLevel=debug
less /var/log/cups/error_log
```

then I can see these error messages:

```
Job stopped due to filter errors; please consult the error_log file for details
HTTP_STATE_WAITING Closing for error 32 (Broken pipe)
```

Some pages I've read before asking:

-[DebuggingPrintingProblems](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems)

Any idea, please?

Comment: Install `wireshark` and use it to watch the packets go between your systems. What does `/var/log/cups/error_log` tell you?

Comment: These are the `error_log` messages:
Job stopped due to filter errors; please consult the error_log file for details
HTTP_STATE_WAITING Closing for error 32 (Broken pipe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally reinstalling the same version of Ubuntu (based on 16.04) has solved all my problems.
Luckily it is quite fast to reinstall Ubuntu if you have separate /home and root partitions.

One big difference between now and before, is that the [Brother supplied script](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=mfcj6910dw_all&os=128#SelectLanguageType-625_0_1) it is now able to download and install the drivers.  It failed before, no matter how many times I tried it.